# Maven Assembly includes filtering

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Given the following dependency inclusion an a Maven assembly XML...

```
<dependencySet>
  <includes>
    <include>com.company.product:library:jar:*:*</include>
  </includes>
```

... why does the above filter fail to include library:jar that doesn't have a classifier?

```
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: assembly/release.xml
[WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter:
o  'com.company.product:library:jar:*:*'
```

The reason for the additional wildcards in my pattern is that I also have a profile that builds all my libraries with the classifier "qa".  When I activate that profile, everything works, but under the default profile (which builds libraries with no classifiers) it fails.

If I change the filter to:

```
<include>com.company.product:library*</include>
```

Then the maven build actually fails, with this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-
plugin:2.3:single (make-assembly) on project java-package: Failed to create 
assembly: Error adding file 'com.company.product:library:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' 
to archive: C:\Subversion\JavaProj\library\target\classes isn't a file. -> [Help 1]
```

Can someone suggest a pattern that will include jars either with or without a classifier?

Answer (score 11):

check your `<dependencies>` in pom.xml: is the dependency you refer in the assembly-xml also there?

Answer (score 2):

Faced with same problem. Do not know why, but `maven-assembly-plugin` does **not** include dependencies with `compile` scope which is default. Making it as `provided` fixes assembling.

E.g. check your `com.company.product:library` dependencies and try to add `<scope>provided</scope>` to them. Then instead of `*` try to list all libraries manally. (You could also try with one of them to check the solution)

Comment: `<scope>provided</scope>` doesn't fix the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

I have recently met the same situation while using *maven-assembly-plugin* (version 3.3.0).
The steps I used to solve it were:

- In POM.xml using the plugin, I added the dependency with `<scope>provided</scope>`
- In the assembly.xml, in the used `dependencySet`:

  - set `<includes><include>[groupId]:[artifactId]:jar</include></includes>` to match the dependency
  - added `<scope>provided</scope>` (because by default *scope=runtime* see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet)

Answer (score 0):

I believe `com.company.product:library*` is failing because you need the colon: `com.company.product:library:*` (see [this chapter from Maven: The Complete Reference](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/assemblies-sect-controlling-contents.html)).

However, rather than banging your head against these wildcards, I suggest creating distinct [component descriptors](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/using-components.html) for your two profiles - qa and non-qa - for the two build profiles. One listing the dependencies having the classifier, one listing the dependencies without the classifier.

Granted, there will be a proliferation of XML files and some redundant content, but it will solve your problem.

Comment: I had tried the filter above also - it should work, but I get the same error, where it seems unable to match a jar with a classifier.  Thanks for the component descriptor suggestion though - I'll look into it.